# boost and qt signal together usage 

Tags: qt, boost, signals-slots

I m using both boost and qt signals and slots together in qt creator. I have followed the [instruction](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/signals/s04.html#id2546691) mentioned. Here is my .pro file

```
QT       += core gui

TARGET = adaptortest
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    adaptor.cpp \
    gstreamer.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    adaptor.h \
    gstreamer.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
LIBS        += -L. -L/usr/lib -lcurl -ltag -fopenmp -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system
CONFIG      += no_keywords # so Qt won't #define any non-all-caps `keywords'
INCLUDEPATH += . /usr/include/boost/



unix:!macx:!symbian: LIBS += -lboost_signals
```

Now I m supposed to use capital QT macros , but for emitting signal neither "emit signalname" nor "Q_EMIT signalname" work. How am I supposed to emit signal in such scenario ?

Answer (score -1):

Emitting signals with macro emit or Q_EMIT is not required. Signals in Qt are just methods of class, so you simply call them as every other method. emit and Q_EMIT are just for visual indication that this particular method is Qt signal

Comment: Not with signals across threads.  Calling function in another thread is dangerous.